# Adding an integer to char array for nice output

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-strings

I am very new to C and am finding that strings in C are giving me quite the headache. I have a program that prints out some data from my struct that holds information on an object. I have an array of these structs and I want to print the data with a nice message. here is the kicker, I am using UDP socket programming and my server handles this information and sends a char array (string) back in which I then print this. Is there an easy way I can achieve this

```
printf("Economy capacity: %d\n", database[index].ecap);
```

but instead of printing it, assign this statement to a char array? this does not work

```
strcpy(output,"Premium capacity: %d\n", database[index].pcap);
```

Comment: I think you are trying to describe `sprintf` or preferably `snprintf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [snprintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).  Just like `printf()` but writes to a `char` array.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Very first C project coming from java….thats all I am going to say about that haha

Answer (score 1):

strcpy is not the function you want to use.
You want to use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/)

```
char output[256];
snprintf(output,256,"Premium capacity: %d\n", database[index].pcap);
```